# JavaScript - Over riding right-click behavior

Tags: javascript, html

A little background first:

I'm designing a web application for a control system that will have a fairly restricted user base (so not everyone and their mother will be using it.)

I have lots of places where I will need a right click menu for doing specific things to the control page. Should I override the right click menu and implement my own or put a small icon or something else to invoke a menu? A good example of the separate icon approach is Google's music beta site. But personally, I hate having to click the little icon; I'd rather right click.

What is considered best practice?

Comment: Google Drive documents is a place where I think the right click override makes a great job!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your application imo. If your application is going to absolutely be limit to desktop users and you have functionality that emulates existing desktop functionality, then I might consider overriding the context menu.

*Having said that*, overriding the context menu violates the [W3C One Web](http://www.w3.org/TR/mobile-bp/#OneWeb) recommendation. If your user base may access your application from devices other than a desktop, you may be limiting them to what they can and can't do in your application (not all devices support right click).

Comment: That is true, as we use iPad quite a bit, i thought that if i went the right click approach I could enable the menu on long touch gestures. Where the user presses and holds his finger in place.

Comment: Do other iPad application have this functionality (I don't have one, so not sure)? If not, then it would seem to me to be counter-intuitive (and a little hack-ish). I'm pretty sure that if I was to use a touch device, I might break it out of frustration before figuring out that I need to hold down on the screen to get what I was looking for (but that may be born of my sheer inexperience using the iPad).

Comment: I only have one at work to develop on so i don't surf the web and play with lots of apps on it. I do know they use the functionality on the main ipad menu to delete and move menu buttons.

Answer (score 1):

The right-click context menu the browser provides is really useful. Please don't disable it through JavaScript. Provide an icon to pop up a menu, or even a series of icons or buttons to replace the menu. You can hide them until they're necessary if you feel they'll clutter up the screen. Twitter's Favorite/Retweet/Reply links are a good example of context-sensitive links appearing without the need for overriding the context menu.